# replaceAll() in JavaScript failed to find </em> in HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, frontend

I am not familiar with JavaScript and html. But I tried to implement a function using JavaScript.

I want to replace all `<em>` and `</em>` in a html page. So I insert a piece of javascript code in the page:

```js
function rep() 
{
    document.body.innerHTML
        = document.body.innerHTML
        .replaceAll("<em>", "_");
    document.body.innerHTML
        = document.body.innerHTML
        .replaceAll("</em>", "_");

}
window.onload=rep()
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<!-- ... -->
<article>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 post-container">

                <p>(Weierstrass) 设 $z_{0}$ 是 $f$ 的本性奇点,那么对任意 $A \in \mathbb{C}<em>{\infty}$, 必存在趋于 $z</em>{0}$ 的点列 $\left{z_{n}\right}$, 使得 $\lim <em>{n \rightarrow \infty} f\left(z</em>{n}\right)=A$.</p>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<!-- ... -->

</html>
```

It succeeded in replacing `<em>` with "_", but all `</em>` did not change. What's wrong with the code?
Thank you!

Comment: can you share your sample HTML with the tags that you want to replace?

Comment: The use of `window.onload` is superfluous because you execute `rep()` and only assign its return value to `window.onload`

Comment: When you set `innerHTML` the first time, the closing `</em>` tags are also removed because that would create invalid HTML

Comment: I'd recommended to use HTML parser for the task, get a list of `em` elements, and unwrap the content from the elements (take a look at [replaceChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/replaceChild) method). Setting `innerHTML` of entire `body` will re-create all the elements, that will lead to various issues sooner or later (perhaps not with this particular page, but it's not useful to learn something you can't use generically).

Answer (score 7):

Let's see what happens when browsers see invalid html like:

```
test</em>
```

```js
console.log(document.body.innerHTML)
```

```html
test</em>
```

The above prints `test` (and the script)

That's because the browser strips invalid structures when parsing

When you do

```
document.body.innerHTML
  = document.body.innerHTML
  .replaceAll("<em>", "_");
```

You replace all `<em>` tags correctly, but the closing tags are removed

This will work on the other hand:

```js
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML
  .replaceAll("<em>", "_")
  .replaceAll("</em>", "_");
```

```html
<em>test</em>
```

Comment: How is your answer different?

Comment: @gog I added some description, but your code was correct as well. I just didn't understand what's different at first

Answer (score 5):

It maybe better to use the available DOM methods for this.

1. Pick up all the `em` elements with `querySelectorAll`.
2. For each element create a text node. Bookend the element's original text content with underscores, and add that to the text node. Use `replaceWith` to replace the `em` element with the text node.

```js
const ems = document.querySelectorAll('em');

ems.forEach(em => {
  const text = `_${em.textContent}_`;
  const node = document.createTextNode(text);
  em.replaceWith(node);
});
```

```html
<p>(Weierstrass) 设 $z_{0}$ 是 $f$ 的本性奇点,那么对任意 $A \in \mathbb{C}<em>{\infty}$, 必存在趋于 $z</em>{0}$ 的点列 $\left{z_{n}\right}$, 使得 $\lim <em>{n \rightarrow \infty} f\left(z</em>{n}\right)=A$.</p>

<ul>
  <li><em>This is some italised text</em></li>
  <li>And this is not.</li>
  <li><em>But this is</em>.</li>
</ul>
```

Additional documentation

- [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)
- [replaceWith](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/replaceWith)
- [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
- [Template/string literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: Sidenote: Intermediate step of creating text nodes is not necessary: Strings added to the DOM are converted to text nodes implicitly. Still good to explicitly convert for showing otherwise hidden steps.

Answer (score 1):

Processing html with regexes or string functions is a bad idea (html is not a string), but if you must, it should be done like this:

```
    let html = document.body.innerHTML
    html = html.replace(...)
    html = html.replace(...) etc
    document.body.innerHTML = html
```

In other words, do not use a partially processed string to set `innerHTML`.

Comment: How is your code different?

Answer (score 0):

Simpler but not efficient:

```
document.body.innerHTML.replace(/\<em\>|\<\/em\>/gm, '_');
```

Result:

```
//body before: <em>test</em>
//body after: _test_
```

The regex will pass over the entire body and will replace all `<em>` or `</em>` occurrences with `_`

The regex options `g` for global and `m` for multiline allow to cover the whole body and multiple occurrences.